# Laravel. Broken query

Tags: php, laravel, join

I have got an error that I don't understand. I've got a `users` table and  `firsts, seconds, thirds` tables.

I wrote a query which should select all users, where status is approved in `firsts, seconds, thirds` tables (depending on status).

At the moment I have user which has `firsts and seconds` status `pending`, but query still finds him. Could you explain what am I doing wrong? What way would you recommend to use in this case? Here is my query:

```
$users = User::whereIn('users.status', array(2, 3))
            ->leftJoin('firsts', 'firsts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('seconds', 'seconds.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('thirds', 'thirds.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where(function($query) {
              $query->where('users.status', 2);
              $query->where('firsts.status', 'approved');
              $query->where('seconds.status', 'approved');
            })
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
              $query->where('users.status', 3);
              $query->where('users.stripe_active', '1');
              $query->orWhere('users.subscription_ends_at', '!=', 'NULL');
              $query->where('firsts.status', 'approved');
              $query->where('seconds.status', 'approved');
              $query->where('thirds.status', 'approved');
            })
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->select('users.id')
            ->get();
```

**EDIT**

So I still can't find a solution. Here is users id's result array: `[3,6,7]`

User with id 3:

```
Firsts status = 'pending',
Seconds status = 'approved',
Thirds status = 'approved'.
```

User with id 6:

```
Firsts status = 'pending',
Seconds status = 'pending',
Thirds status = 'approved'.
```

User with id 7:

```
Firsts status = 'approved',
Seconds status = 'approved',
Thirds status = 'approved'.
```

As you can see `user` with `id 3` and `6` should not be in array.

Comment: I think laravel has no 'leftjoin'. It should be join

Comment: @aldrin27 of course Laravel has [`leftJoin`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L378-L381). It's an helper method that calls `join`, automatically setting the `$type` parameter value to `left`.

Comment: @Bogdan Oh I see. Because I use only the join function.

Comment: Wops. I was wrong. Nothing changed :(

Comment: @EvaldasButkus maybe try using sub-queries then union-all?

Comment: @EvaldasButkus You should grab the resulting query and post it here. You can learn how to do it here http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/display-all-sql-executed-in-eloquent. In case the suggested method does not work try the code in the first comment.

Comment: You can change your `->get()` to `->toSql()` and see where things go wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not filter data from third table where user.status = 2 and rearrange your where clauses where user.status =3

Better join only those users whose status is approved. This will speed up the query.

```
$users = User::whereIn('users.status', array(2, 3))
            ->leftJoin('firsts', function($join){
                $join->on('firsts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                     ->where('firsts.status','=', 'approved');
                })
            ->leftJoin('seconds', function($join){
                $join->on('seconds.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                     ->where('seconds.status','=', 'approved');
                })
            ->leftJoin('thirds', function($join){
                $join->on('thirds.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                     ->where('third.status','=','approved');
                })
            ->where(function($query) {
              $query->where('users.status', 2);
              $query->where('firsts.status','=', 'approved');
              $query->where('seconds.status','=', 'approved');
              $query->where('thirds.status','=', 'approved');  
            })
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
              $query->where('users.status', 3);
              $query->where(function($q){
                  $q->where('users.stripe_active', '1');
                  $q->orWhereNotNull('users.subscription_ends_at');
              });
              $query->where('firsts.status','=', 'approved');
              $query->where('seconds.status','=', 'approved');
              $query->where('thirds.status','=', 'approved');
            })
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->select(['users.id'])
            ->get();
```

Comment: I did try your query. Still getting bad results

Comment: both are with status `3`

Comment: if you edit a query like in (updated) answer, does it makes any changes

Comment: I appreciate your help but even now it doesn't help.  Now querry doesn't pull any users.

Comment: I modified my database a bit and it started working. I used your query. Thanks!